# Xamarin.Android Adapter GetString not working

Tags: xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I'm using `Resources.System.GetString(Resource.String.no_of_bags)` inside my `RecyclerView`. This class doesn't contain reference for context/Activity. I'm getting runtime exception.

Comment: You would normally pass in the context as part of the constructor. Store it as a local variable inside of the adapter and then use it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Digitalsa1nt has said, you need pass the `Context` to your Adapter.

[Here is the official demo](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/layouts/recycler-view/recyclerview-example/) about the usage of `RecyclerView`, but it doesn't refer to the `Context` when create an instance of `PhotoAlbumAdapter`.

You can do like this:

1) Add `Context` in the `PhotoAlbumAdapter` class

```
public class PhotoAlbumAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    Context mContext;
    PhotoAlbum mPhotoAlbum;
    public PhotoAlbumAdapter(Context context, PhotoAlbum photoAlbum)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mPhotoAlbum = photoAlbum;
    }
    ...
}
```

2) Pass `this` (this is the instance of MainActivity) to `PhotoAlbumAdapter`

```
mAdapter = new PhotoAlbumAdapter(this,mphotoAlbum);
```

3) Use `mContext` in `OnBindViewHolder` method

```
    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        mContext.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.no_of_bags);
    }
```

Comment: but im initializing the string array variable inside the class and outside methods. EG: private String[] sample={"1","sample","this",}; this values i need to fetch from strings.xml

Comment: By `inside the class and outside methods`, I can't understand it. Could you please post the codes in your question?

Comment: public class SettingsLandingListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        

       ....

        private String[] data = { "Print ", "QR Code Printer", "Enable/Disable Bluetooth", "Enable/Disable Wifi", "QR Code Bluetooth", "Reset Weighing" };.....

Comment: You can use `mContext.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.no_of_bags);` in the `PhotoAlbumAdapter(Context context, PhotoAlbum photoAlbum)` construction method. And I am not sure what is your problem? Do you want use `Context/Activity` in your `SettingsLandingListAdapter` class? Please edit your problem, the code in comment is difficult to read.